# Connection reset by peer and CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a server working with sockets and TCP protocol, I'm using OpenSSL. I'm getting an error after stablish a bunch of connections.What happens is that a lot of sockets remain in CLOSE_WAIT state. I looked the log of my app and the code and I have an errno=104 that I searched and in linux (my OS) is a

> connection reset by peer

My app is in C++ and I want to know which scenarios can cause this. I mean this only happen when the server tries to close connection and in the socket there are still some information that is not read by the client? If so how can avoid this? Can be a certification problem? Thanks

My code to close server connection is like this.

```
int lErrorCode = 0;
    int lErrno = 0;
    int lSSLErrorCode = 0;
    long int lSSLErrorAdditionalCode = 0;
    while (!lErrorCode)
    {
        lSSLErrorCode = SSL_get_error(pSSL, lErrorCode);
        lSSLErrorAdditionalCode = ERR_get_error();
        usleep(10);
    }
    if (lErrorCode == -1)
    {
        cout << "shutdown error" << endl;
        if (_log_iface)
        {
            char lSSLErrorString[120];
            ERR_error_string(lSSLErrorAdditionalCode, lSSLErrorString);

            string ssl_error_desc;
            switch (lSSLErrorCode)
            {
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_NONE";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL";
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                ssl_error_desc = "SSL_ERROR_SSL";
                break;
            default:
                ssl_error_desc = "[unknown]";
                break;
            }

//HERE LOG THE ERROR MESSAGE
```

Comment: _something like this_ would be a good idea to post real code.

Comment: Ok I will edit, but that's the real code hahaha